# Unwanted \hline in \longtable header

Tags: tables, longtable

Observe the following minimum listing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=6cm,paperheight=5cm}%a very small page
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,multicol}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \begin{longtable}{ll}
        \caption{My longtable} \\   
        \toprule
        col 1 & col 2 \\ \midrule
        \endhead
        1 & 2\\\hline   1 & 2\\\hline   1 & 2\\\hline   1 & 2\\\hline   \multicolumn{2}{c}{see the double line above?} \\\hline   1 & 2\\\hline   1 & 2\\\hline   1 & 2\\   \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

The table expands to the second page. Now, it is supposed to repeat the \midrule of the header on the second page too. But it also adds the \hline, which results in two parallel lines (see the picture representing the second page). Is there a way to suppress the \hline after the header?

Note that if a \hline is put in place of \midrule, there is no doubling in the second page header.

[image]

Comment: the \hline is doubled, but longtable inserts a fraction of negative space so that the two hlines overlap. You can't do that with `\midrule` as it has the vertical space to separate it from the surroundings. You need to remove the `\hline`  (in  most tables you can remove all the hline and it will look better)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle unfortunately I can't remove all the \hlines because my real table is a complex one, and the horizontal separation is unavoidable

Comment: well you need to remove the bad ones by hand, sorry. blame the author of longtable....